# openlayers : tile layer from v 5.3.0 to v 6.12.0

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

I try to update this layer from ol v 5.3.0 to 6.12.0
and the error is "ReferenceError: TileLayer is not defined" as if the function was not loaded from the ol library call :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/iliad/bibliotheques_javascript/olv6.12.0/css/ol.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/iliad/bibliotheques_javascript/olv6.12.0/build/ol.js" data-url="/iliad/autoconfINRAP.json"></script>
```

the layer code en v5.3.0

```
var osmLyr = new ol.layer.Tile({
    olParams: {
        crossOrigin: "Anonymous",
    },
    source: new ol.source.OSM(),
    opacity: 1,
    name: 'Carte Osm',
    description: "carte open street map, https://www.openstreetmap.org"
});
```

and the v6.12.0 code

```
    var osmLyr = new TileLayer({
        source: new OSM(),
sourceParams: {
            crossOrigin: "Anonymous"
        },
        opacity: 1,
        name: 'Carte Osm',
        description: "carte open street map, https://www.openstreetmap.org"
  });
```

Comment: If you are using ol.js build instead of modules you should continue to use this format https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/quickstart.html

Comment: If you are using the legacy build (ol.js), you still need the `ol.layer.Tile` and `ol.source.OSM` (like Mike said).

Comment: ok
 in the api it's not so clear and does not mention this subtlety that you indicate .
the function is given as
new TileLayer(opt_options).
so in the api I have to convert everything from ol/layer/Tile to ol.layer.Tile 
Thanks